# how to simulate Ctrl + V using keybd_event () in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard-events

i want to paste text from clipboard to some program's textbox. so i tried to use keybd_event.

```
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0x1D, 0, 0);
keybd_event('V', 0x2F, 0, 0);
keybd_event('V', 0x2F, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0x1D, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

but this is not executed. so i tried different way

```
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0x1D,  KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event('V', 0x2F, 0, 0);
keybd_event('V', 0x2F, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0x1D, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

so this work well. However, since then, all keyboard inputs have been entered with the ctrl key pressed.
maybe i think key-up message is not worked

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Scan codes are hardware specific, so don't use hard-coded values, use `MapVirtualKey/Ex()` instead. But in any case, `keybd_event()` is old and deprecated, use `SendInput()` instead (the `keybd_event()` documentation even says so).  Give it an array of down/up keystrokes to send in a single call. And it can be used with just virtual key codes, you don't need to use scan codes.

Comment: Hi MX-4, does my solution work for you?

Comment: Hi MX-4, feel free let me know if you still have any concern about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> However, since then, all keyboard inputs have been entered with the
>   ctrl key pressed. maybe i think key-up message is not worked

You simulate right `CONTROL` `WM_KEYDOWN` but left `CONTROL` `WM_KEYUP`. **So the right-hand `CTRL` key has not been released.**

The following code will work:

```
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0x1D, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);
keybd_event('V', 0x2F, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);
keybd_event('V', 0x2F, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0x1D, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

> extended-key flag (`KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY`)
>
> Indicates whether the key is an extended key, such as the right-hand
>   ALT and CTRL keys that appear on an enhanced 101- or 102-key keyboard.
>   The value is 1 if it is an extended key; otherwise, it is 0.

Refer to [`WM_KEYUP` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup).

**keybd_event function has been superseded. Use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.**